# Check which GPU a process is using

Tags: fedora, gpu, amd-graphics

I have a notebook with an Intel iGPU and a dedicated AMD GPU and I was told that by default the iGPU would be used, but that I can explicitly tell a program use the AMD GPU by running it like this

```
DRI_PRIME=1 example_program
```

I know that this works for glmark2 because it tells me in the terminal, but how can I verify this for any other process?

For nvidia GPUs there apparently is a utility called `nvidia-smi`, but I need something that works for AMD  GPUs.

I'm using Fedora 34 in case it matters...

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your GPU:

- AMD Radeon: [`radeontop`](https://pkgs.org/download/radeontop)
- Intel Graphics: [`intel-gpu-tools`](https://pkgs.org/download/intel-gpu-tools)
- Nvidia GeForce: [`nvidia-smi`](https://pkgs.org/download/nvidia-smi)

To see which process your Radeon uses, look for [`radeon-profile`](https://pkgs.org/download/radeon-profile):

[image: radeon-profile]

Comment: Please provide more detail. Non of the `radeontop` options make it show which process is using the GPU from what I can tell.

Comment: Ok that's clearer now, I've updated my answer.

Comment: `radeon-profile` doesn't show anything for my AMD Vega GPU.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know any other tools. You can to some extent do the same of what you want by looking at your iGPU usage with `intel-gpu-tools` and run your program with `radeon-profile`. If no iGPU usage shows up but your does on your whole Vega, you can be pretty sure that your program does not run on your iGPU.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if this applicable to your case, but the following command helps to determine the CPU core a process with pid is executing:

## ps -o pid,psr,cmd -p

Comment: This command would be very interesting if the question wasn't about GPU, not CPU :-)